# What can one tell about matrix power by looking at it?

Tags: matrices

By looking at a straightforward Markov chain I am able to tell it's transition matrix easily
$$P =\begin{pmatrix}1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\ 0 & 2/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\ 0 & 0 & 3/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 4/6 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5/6 & 1/6 \\ 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix};$$

I realize that the limit is going to be
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}P^n =\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0&0&0&1 \\0 & 0 & 0&0&0&1 \\0 & 0 & 0&0&0&1 \\0 & 0 & 0&0&0&1 \\0 & 0 & 0&0&0&1 \\0 & 0 & 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix};$$

But my lecturer told "You have to be able to tell more. Think about it." Now by saying that he must mean that one may be able to tell the exact $P^n$ for every natural $n$ (because there is nothing more about this problem)... But is that really possible given that I'm just an undergraduate?

Lower triangular part of such matrix is trivial. For example an element of $P^n$ in 1st row and 2nd column is the same element of $P^{n-1}$ multiplied by $2$ and $1$ added to it. I see similar recursive relations for all other elements, but I used computer to be sure about the patterns - otherwise it would take way too long...

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algebraic way is to look at the eigendecomposition. Note that for a triangular matrix, the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries, i.e.,
$$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \dfrac26 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \dfrac36 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac46 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac56 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
The eigenvectors form the matrix.
$$V = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \dfrac1{\sqrt2} & \dfrac1{\sqrt3} & \dfrac1{\sqrt4} & \dfrac1{\sqrt5} & \dfrac1{\sqrt6}\\
0 & \dfrac1{\sqrt2} & \dfrac1{\sqrt3} & \dfrac1{\sqrt4} & \dfrac1{\sqrt5} & \dfrac1{\sqrt6}\\
0 & 0 & \dfrac1{\sqrt3} & \dfrac1{\sqrt4} & \dfrac1{\sqrt5} & \dfrac1{\sqrt6}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac1{\sqrt4} & \dfrac1{\sqrt5} & \dfrac1{\sqrt6}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac1{\sqrt5} & \dfrac1{\sqrt6}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac1{\sqrt6}
\end{bmatrix}$$
We also have that
$$V^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & {\sqrt2} & -{\sqrt2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & -\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & {\sqrt4} & -{\sqrt4} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\sqrt5} & -{\sqrt5}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\sqrt6}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, we have
$$P^n = V \Lambda^n V^{-1}$$
Now $\Lambda^n V^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
(1/6)^n & -(1/6)^n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & {\sqrt2}(2/6)^n & -{\sqrt2}(2/6)^n & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3}(3/6)^n & -\sqrt{3}(3/6)^n & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & {\sqrt4}(4/6)^n & -{\sqrt4}(4/6)^n & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\sqrt5}(5/6)^n & -{\sqrt5}(5/6)^n\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {\sqrt6}
\end{bmatrix}$
Hence,
$$P^n = \begin{bmatrix}
(1/6)^n & (2^n-1^n)/6^n & (3^n-2^n)/6^n & (4^n-3^n)/6^n & (5^n-4^n)/6^n & (6^n-5^n)/6^n\\
0 & 2^n/6^n & (3^n-2^n)/6^n & (4^n-3^n)/6^n & (5^n-4^n)/6^n & (6^n-5^n)/6^n\\
0 & 0 & 3^n/6^n & (4^n-3^n)/6^n & (5^n-4^n)/6^n & (6^n-5^n)/6^n\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 4^n/6^n & (5^n-4^n)/6^n & (6^n-5^n)/6^n\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5^n/6^n & (6^n-5^n)/6^n\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} (\star)$$
Can you now come up with a combinatorial argument why $P^n$ is of the form $(\star)$?

Comment: Numerators of upper-part elements are numbers of combinations which satisfy the outcome! And that's just sweet!

Answer (score 2):

> Look for the path of the underlying process...

The transition matrix $P$ on the state space $\{1,2,\ldots,6\}$ corresponds to the dynamics $x\to\max(x,u)$, where $u$ is uniform on $S$. Thus, a realization of the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ is 
$$
X_n=\max\{X_0,U_1,\ldots,U_n\},
$$ 
for every $n\geqslant0$, where $(U_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ is i.i.d. uniform on $\{1,2,\ldots,6\}$ and independent of $X_0$.

In particular, $P[X_n\leqslant x]=P[X_0\leqslant x]\cdot P[U\leqslant x]^n=P[X_0\leqslant x]\cdot(x/6)^n$, from which a formula for $P[X_n=x]$ for every $1\leqslant x\leqslant 6$ can be deduced.

Comment: I accepted other fellow's answer because I understood it very quickly. I need to give this some more thought, but I honestly like this approach. I hope that after leaving out probabilities involving $X_0$ it will lead to all the elements of $P^n$.

Comment: Of course it does (why do you think I would have explained this approach otherwise?). To get the line $P^n(x,\ )$ of the matrix $P^n$, assume that $X_0=x$ almost surely, then $P[X_0\leqslant y]=\mathbf 1_{x\leqslant y}$ hence $P[X_n\leqslant y\mid X_0=x]=\mathbf 1_{x\leqslant y}\cdot(y/6)^n$ and $P^n(x,y)=\mathbf 1_{x\leqslant y}\cdot(y/6)^n-\mathbf 1_{x\leqslant y-1}\cdot((y-1)/6)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Show that a pattern holding at one power implies it holds for the next. Then show that the pattern holds between some specific power and the next. Then assume the axiom of induction, and you can conclude that means it holds for all powers after that.

Comment: Axiom of choice?

Comment: Or the well-ordering theorem.

Comment: I was confused though, that's strong induction.

Comment: The "well-ordering principle" that is relevant for induction only concerns subsets of the _natural numbers_. The "well-ordering theorem" that is equivalent to AC says that _every_ set can be well-ordered.

Comment: Anyway, I think just saying "use mathematical induction" (rather than "assume the axiom of induction") is probably a more appropriate answer in this case.

Comment: That makes sense. It's a personal policy of mine to indicate, whenever possible, that something intuitively obviously true I'm suggesting as proof is in fact only true by axiom.